# How do I hide a form field from sight, validation and submission?

Tags: html, validation

### Example

1. I have two form fields (a) Sex (b) Sexual orientation
2. If male and het., the question "How tall is your girlfriend?" is required. It may also have a value, there may be other applicable rules (i.e. [max 2.41m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Bunford)).
3. User should be able to submit the form, but I don't want the preset value to arrive on the server if the question was never shown. I also don't want the required attribute or an invalid value to prevent submission (but I don't want to turn off form validation).

`<div style="display:none" data-showif="sex == 'm' & orientation == 'het'">My girlfriend is this <input type="number" min="1" max="2.41" step="0.01" value="1.7" required> tall.</div>`

Now, this is actually more general.

The rules for showing (2) or not are custom, maybe it's not even possible to say if they can be validated in the browser before runtime. 
The rules applicable to (2) are custom too, and might go beyond the required attribute (whose state I could remember and temporarily turn off).

Maybe the user has JS turned off so dynamically showing (2) doesn't work, but form validation works and blocks submission.

Maybe the user is unsure about his heterosexuality and specifies an invalid tallness, then changes his mind and the question is hidden again, but blocks submission.

I am basically looking for `novalidate` and `nosubmit` but on the `input` level, not on the `<form>` level.

Comment: even in a self-answering question, you should still post the code you're working with. Other people looking for this question would want to see some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is probably obvious to everybody, but I actually spent time googling this and writing the question, because I was coming at it from the "prevent validation" problem originally.
It came to me, while writing this, so I thought it might save the next mentally challenged person some precious brain time.

The attribute is called `disabled`.